# How can we create Randolph diagrams in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, visualization, logic

I have become fascinated with [Randolph Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randolph_diagram) and was wondering how we would create the diagrams from logical sequences using *Mathematica*?

It looks like it would be a combination of logic and graphing.  I have no idea where to start.  I need some suggestions to get me going.

**Edit:** [Randolph's paper on JStor](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2310972)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This could provide a good starting point, since the structure of the diagrams is simply a cross with four regions that themselves can contain similar crosses, you can simply define a structure to represent this nesting and a recursive function to draw such structures. In my implementation I just use the head `c` to indicate a cross:

```
dirs = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};

cross[mid_, scale_] := {
 Thickness[0.02 scale],
 Line[{scale {-1, -1} + mid, scale {1, 1} + mid}],
 Line[{scale {1, -1} + mid, scale {-1, 1} + mid}]
}

rDraw[True, mid_, scale_] := Disk[mid, scale]
rDraw[False, ___] := {}
rDraw[c[a__], mid_: {0, 0}, scale_: 1] := {cross[mid, scale], 
 Sequence @@ MapIndexed[
   rDraw[#1, mid + scale  dirs[[#2[[1]]]], 0.45 scale] &, {a}]}
```

So then you can create a diagram via:

```
With[{t = True, f = False},
 rDraw@c[t, f, c[f, c[f, t, c[f, t, f, t], f], t, f], f] // Graphics
]
```

[image: an image showing a diagram plot]

Now it is just a question of converting expressions like `(A&B) or !C` into this `c[...]` structure.

Here's a small graph of some simple operations:

```
With[{t = True, f = False},
 Graphics[rDraw[#2], PlotLabel -> #1] & @@@ {
    {"and", c[f, t]},
    {"Nand", c[t, f, t, t]},
    {"or", c[t, t, t]},
    {"Nor", c[f, f, f, t]}
    } // GraphicsRow
]
```

[image: Simple operations diagrams]