# How do I transform a 1st order logic formula into Skolem normal form?

Tags: homework, logic

I have a predicate calculus (first-order logic) problem. I have the formula

$\qquad \forall x[\neg P(x) \land \forall y \neg Q(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \forall y R(x,y,z)]$

I want to express this in [Skolem normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form). How can I [do this](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~sheila/384/w11/Lectures/csc384w11-KR-tutorial.pdf) using Mathematica?

Comment: Please consider adding more detail and some Wolfram Language code (even if it's just your equation) to your question. What is a skolem shape - are they related to [Randolph diagrams](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-can-we-create-randolph-diagrams-in-mathematica?rq=1)? What have you tried so far and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @CarlLange, I mean skolem normal form